# Assigning an index register to a general purpose register

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am dividing each value within the array (arr) with 2 to check the reminder of the division and decide whether it's an odd or even value. The problem is whenever I assign the first value of arr (1) to the reg ax, the value being stored in reg ax is 0201h not 0001h. I can't really figure out why 0201 is stored not 0001.

```
arr db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

```
LEA SI, arr
```

```
mov ax,[SI]    ; the value 0201h is stored instead of 0001h
```

The original code

```
.Model small
.stack 64
.data
arr db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
countEven db ?
avgResult db ?
.code
;description
Main PROC Far
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    LEA SI, arr
    mov countEven, 0
    mov cx,10   ;the size of the array
    mov bh,2    ;the value 2 to be divided by
    mov dx,0    ;the sum container
    loop1:  mov ax,[SI]
            DIV bh
            cmp ah,1    ;if ah = 1, then value within ax was odd (reminder of division by 2 is 1)
            JE skip
            add dx,[SI]
            Inc countEven
            skip: add SI,1
    Loop loop1
    mov ax,dx       ;ax contains the sum
    mov bh,countEven;bx contains the no. of even elements
    div bh          ;ax is the final avg result of the even numbers, where ax=ax/bx
    mov avgResult, al

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    
Main ENDP
End Main
```

Comment: The array elements are one byte each, but it is loading into ax, so it is loading two bytes.

Comment: By the way, using DIV is very nearly the worst possible way to decide if a number is odd. `test al, 1` is a better way.

Comment: To load one byte from memory into ax, do this: `mov ah, 0; mov al, [si]`. Also change `add dx, [si]` to `add dx, ax` so you don’t have to read it from memory again.

Comment: Re the comment “ax is the final avg result”, `div bh` is an 8-bit division, so the result is in al, not ax.

Comment: Concerning your 3rd comment, you have suggested changing ```add dx,[si]``` to ```add dx, ax``` , but, according to what I understand from the division process, after division ax doesn't contain any more the original value, instead, it contains (reminder, quotient) (ah,al) ??

Comment: Right, that suggestion only works together with the previous suggestion.